# How to make share path monitoring script to generate outlook email alert if no movement appears in shard path after 20 minutes?

Tags: python-3.x, automation, alert, monitor, python-watchdog

Greetings!! I am trying using below watchdog module to monitor a shared path that works fine but I am not getting the idea to
generate outlook email alert, after the time span of 20 minutes if no
modification or update happening to the specified path. Below is the
code:

```
import os
import sys
import time
import logging

from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import LoggingEventHandler

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    os.system('//fleet.ad/data/Data4/VMSSHARE/its/DOCS')


    print("found")
    # Defining your own path
    path = "//bleet.ad/data/Data4/VMSSHARE/its/DOCS"
    print("found")


    # Initilaize logging event handler
    event_handler = LoggingEventHandler()

    # Initialize Observer
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)

    # Start the observer
    observer.start()
    
    try:
        while True:
            # set the thread sleep time
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

However, tried this piece of code to receive outlook email alerts, but not sure how to make it work with above script:

```
import os
import smtplib
import requests

EMAIL_ADDRESS = os.environ.get('USER_ID')
EMAIL_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('USER_PASSWORD')

r = requests.get("https://fleet.my.salesforce.com", timeout=5)

#if r.status_code!= 200:
with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com', 587) as smtp:
    smtp.ehlo()
    smtp.starttls()
    smtp.ehlo()
    smtp.login(EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL_PASSWORD)

    subject = 'ALARM: MAPILab is stuck from copying Public folders to destination'
    body = 'Make sure server is restarted and it is backed up'
    msg = f'Subject:{subject}\n\n{body}'

    smtp.sendmail(EMAIL_ADDRESS, 'ryadav@elementcorp.com', msg)
```

Challenge for me is :

```
r = requests.get("https://fleet.my.salesforce.com", timeout=5)
```

Instead of website monitor , how should I ask to look for the code output?

Comment: Greetings. Please try to limit your code to the minimum necessary to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to attach methods to your event handler, like this:

```
my_event_handler.on_created = on_created
my_event_handler.on_deleted = on_deleted
my_event_handler.on_modified = on_modified
my_event_handler.on_moved = on_moved
```

where the methods look like:

```
def on_created(event):
     print(f"{event.src_path} has been created!")
```

as described in this blog post: http://thepythoncorner.com/dev/how-to-create-a-watchdog-in-python-to-look-for-filesystem-changes/

Have your handlers update a `last_changed` timestamp variable whenever there is a change. (Since all your handlers do the same thing regardless of what the change was, you could get away with just defining one handler method, maybe call it `on_any_change` and attach it to all 4 handler methods. Oh look, the [`watchdog` docs](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/api.html#event-handler-classes) show that there is an `on_any_event` method, so you could just hook into that.)

Then in your `while True` loop, if the current time - `last_changed` is greater than your threshold, send the email.

Comment: it was really helpful to understand . Can you please help with the while loop as well . I am not getting how to set this condition. And really appreciate your help. Thank you